# Importing an HTML template in Grails

Tags: javascript, html, grails, groovy, underscore.js-templating

I'd like to pull in a static HTML file that I'll use as an Underscore template in my front-end JavaScript. I've tried the following with no luck:

```
<link rel="import" href="${resource(plugin: 'my-app-name', dir: 'tpl', file: 'foo.html')}"/>
<g:external dir="tpl" file="foo.html" type="html" />
```

The file sits at web-app/tpl/foo.html.

The ultimate goal is to use the new HTML import syntax to access the file's contents via JavaScript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following worked for me, though I'm not sure if it's the best solution: In UrMappings.groovy: `static excludes = ['tpl/foo.html']`. This made the link tag work in page.gsp `<link rel="import" href="${resource(plugin: 'my-app-name', dir: 'tpl', file: 'foo.html')}"/>`.

Answer (score 0):

Why is that file at `web-app/tpl`?

Here's what you can do to import that template:

1. Move it to `grails-app/views/tpl/`.
2. Change the file name to `_foo.gsp`.
3. Use `<g:render template="/tpl/foo" />` in your view to pull in that HTML.

Read more about the render tag [here](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Tags/render.html).

Comment: Hello Grant, thank you for your answer. I'm not using a GSP because it's an Underscore template for use in Backbone (JavaScript).

Answer (score 0):

Also you can use an meta tag.

```
 <meta name="layout" content="main"/>
```

And in the main.gsp tha must be at the view/layout/main.gsp you can use grails tags:

```
<g:layoutHead/>
```

and

```
<g:layoutBody/>
```

By the name you can understand that layoutHead insert head of your page to this layout. layout body insert body of page to this layout.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Koloritnij. As mentioned in my question, the purpose of this is to pull in an Underscore template using the new HTML import syntax. I have plenty of GSP views in the same app, but this is an opportunity to showcase a new feature of HTML.